# Controlling text-mode output in Linux | C / C++

Tags: linux, text, interface, mode

First, I apologize for any sillinesses that might occur, as I'm not quite sure as how to properly put this question.

I recently got curious about how some applications (like Midnight Commander) control the text-mode output, forming so-called "Text-based user interface", idk. Is that some evil magic with standard output operations or something else that I'm unaware of? I did some poking around google, but didn't find anything of particular interest, and I hope someone here can point me on the right way.

Thanks in advance,

~Insomnia Array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is NCurses - a library which uses special terminal characters to set color, position, etc.

http://www.gnu.org/s/ncurses/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to ncurses, take a look at S-lang.

http://www.s-lang.org/